# how to add onchange events to ul and li based drop down list which is created using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create drop down list using bootstrap but also i wanted to add java script event of onchange when user will select a particular item of given list.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Show some code.

Comment: solved long back thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add event listeners to `ul` and `li`, you add them to the underlying `<select>`:

```
$('select#myselect').selectpicker().on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
$('select#myselect').selectpicker();
$('select#myselect').on('change', function() {

    // this => select element in this context
    // .val() here is going to get the selected value
    console.log($(this).val());

    // if you want to check if a specific value is selected
    if ($(this).val() === 2) {
        // do something specific
    }
});
```